# Creating Custom view in mscrm 2011 error

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

When I create a custom view in Mscrm 2011 for link entity query using below syntax for adding new custom view:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(lookupFieldName).addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
```

I don't get an error while debugging this javascript but when i try to open the lookup I get below error

> *To use this saved view, you must remove criteria and columns that refer to deleted or non-searchable items*

Attached is the screen shot:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using wrong schema names. Check them! Use a program to check the XML fetch (I use SWTools). Then check the grid. You just need a single column schema name  wrong to break the XML! Usually it's just a capital letter that breaks the grid, or something similarly small.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your fetchXml. Does this contain all the attribute which is set for the Lookup?

Download the fetchxml from the advance find view which you have set on that lookup and update the fetchxml with the filter criteria that you want to use.